# one view in other view not showing in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

List view page

```
@model IEnumerable<project_name.Models.ProductTypeCategoryVM>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
```

Create view

```
@model project_name.Models.ProductTypeCategoryVM

@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@{Html.Action("ProductCategory_List", "Home");}    

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
```

but once I load Create page I can see only create page not the create page with list ,

Comment: can you plese post `ProductCategory_List` action.Are you getting any error?

Comment: @shu Im not getting any error only thing is I cant see table view above the create page

Comment: Check you console for any client side errors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some extra parenthesis in your code. Change

```
@{Html.Action("ProductCategory_List", "Home");}
```

to

```
@Html.Action("ProductCategory_List", "Home")
```

Comment: The 2nd one need to have the `;` removed (and the first one would have worked if it was `@{ Html.RenderAction(); }`

Comment: @Candide I missed out the brackets , great observations :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke You're right on both comments. I removed the `;`

Comment: but once removed that colon(;) getting an error `Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\2aebfed2\f7c40b57\App_Web_productcategory_create.cshtml.a8d08dba.fcvk_qtf.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus.`

Comment: @kez, The error has got nothing to do with removing the `;` - read the error - _because the file contains a virus_ should be self explanatory

Comment: but this error vanish once I add ; end of `@Html.Action("ProductCategory_List", "Home")`

Comment: shall I delete this `App_Web_productcategory_create.cshtml.a8d08dba.k4yoinlp.dll` file ?

Comment: @kez LOL, you should scan your computer for viruses.